# 'do something' every time a counter increase of 1000

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, count

well I have a counter of collision between two images (the counter is the score of my game) and I would like to `do something` every time the counter is 1000, or 2000 or 3000 ... every ten thousands.How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say 10,000 but you write 1000, here is what I would do for 1000:

```
if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
    //Do something.
}
```

For 10,000 do:

```
if (counter % 10000 == 0) {
    //Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(counter%1000 == 0) {
//do something
}
```